# how to stop the program if the value i get for amount_notes is not an integer?

Tags: c, integer

Anyone know how to solve this problem? I want my program to be stop if the value of amount_notes is not an integer...But it still continue run although the value of amount_notes has decimal place or remainder...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define acc_balance 5000.00

int main()
{

   //variables decleration
    int rm_100, rm_50, rm_20, rm_10;
    float total_notes, total_100, total_50, total_20, total_10;
    float total_amount, balance_amount;
    int amount_notes;
    float withdraw_amount, withdraw_balance;


   // input
    printf("DEPOSIT SYSTEM\n\n");
    printf("Your balance is RM %.2lf\n\n", acc_balance);

    printf("Please key in the amount of notes for Cash Deposit :\n");
    printf("The number of RM 100 notes : ");
    scanf("%d", &rm_100);
    printf("The number of RM  50 notes : ");
    scanf("%d", &rm_50);
    printf("The number of RM  20 notes : ");
    scanf("%d", &rm_20);
    printf("The number of RM  10 notes : ");
    scanf("%d", &rm_10);

   //process
    total_notes = rm_10 + rm_20 + rm_50 + rm_100;

    if (total_notes > 100) {

        printf("\nThe process is unsuccessful because total exceed 99 notes.\n");

        return 0;
    }else{

        printf("\n");
        printf("Deposit Successful. You have deposit the following notes amount :\n");

        total_100 = 100 * rm_100;
        printf("RM 100 X %3d = RM %5.2f\n", rm_100, total_100);

        total_50 = 50 * rm_50;
        printf("RM  50 X %3d = RM %5.2f\n", rm_50, total_50);

        total_20 = 20 * rm_20;
        printf("RM  20 X %3d = RM %5.2f\n", rm_20, total_20);

        total_10 = 10 * rm_10;
        printf("RM  10 X %3d = RM %5.2f\n", rm_10, total_10);

        total_amount = total_100 + total_50 + total_20 + total_10;
        printf("\n\tTotal \t= RM %5.2f\n", total_amount);

        balance_amount = acc_balance + total_amount;
        printf("\nYour balance is now RM %.2f\n", balance_amount);

    }

    printf("\nWITHDRAWAL SYSTEM\n");

    printf("\nYour withdrawal balance is RM %.2f\n", balance_amount);

    printf("\nAmount to be Withdrawn : RM ");
    scanf("%f", &withdraw_amount);

    amount_notes = withdraw_amount / 50;
    withdraw_balance = balance_amount - withdraw_amount;

    if (withdraw_balance < 20) {

        printf("Insufficient Funds - Minimum Balance of RM20 must remain in your account.\n");

        return 0;

    }if (withdraw_amount <= 0) {

        printf("Invalid amount - Ensure the amount is greater than 0.\n");

        return 0;

    }if (amount_notes != (int)amount_notes) {
    //HERE THE PROBLEM, HOW TO STOP HERE IF THE AMOUNT_NOTES IN NOT AN INTEGER
        printf("Invalid amount - Ensure the amount is a multiple of 50.\n");

        return 0;

    }else{

        printf("\nWithdrawal Successful...\n");
        printf("\t%d notes X RM 50 = RM %.2f\n", amount_notes, withdraw_amount);

        printf("\nYour balance is now RM %.2f\n", withdraw_balance);

        return 0;

    }

}
```

The results show like this :

```
DEPOSIT SYSTEM

Your balance is RM 5000.00

Please key in the amount of notes for Cash Deposit :
The number of RM 100 notes : 10
The number of RM  50 notes : 10
The number of RM  20 notes : 10
The number of RM  10 notes : 10

Deposit Successful. You have deposit the following notes amount :
RM 100 X  10 = RM 1000.00
RM  50 X  10 = RM 500.00
RM  20 X  10 = RM 200.00
RM  10 X  10 = RM 100.00

    Total   = RM 1800.00

Your balance is now RM 6800.00

WITHDRAWAL SYSTEM

Your withdrawal balance is RM 6800.00

Amount to be Withdrawn : RM 300.50

//THE PROGRAM DIDN'T STOP HERE ALTHOUGH THE AMOUNT TO BE WITHDRAW HAS DECIMAL THAT SHOULDN'T BE SUCCESSFUL WITHDRAWAL ACTUALLY

Withdrawal Successful...
    6 notes X RM 50 = RM 300.50

Your balance is now RM 6499.50
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

How to solve this problem?? Need help...

Comment: Problem: the number 1.0e+300 is an integer too. (example number)

Comment: Your comparison will always be successful as your amount_notes is an int, and when you compare amount_notes to (int) amount_notes, this will always be equal.

Comment: strongly suggest only one variable declaration per line.  Then, in the real world, it is easy to comment the variable and easy for documentation tools to acquire the variable and its' attending documentation.

Comment: this line: 'if (total_notes > 100) {' and the following printf() have a logic error.  They do not account for when the total count is exactly 100  Suggest changing either the literal 100 to 99 or changing the text in the printf() statement

Comment: when using literals for float values write them as 10.0f  (the '.' and the 'f' are required to produce a float literal.   If 'amount_notes' were a float, then check for integer using: '}if (amount_notes != floor(amount_notes)) {'  suggest placing new statements on new lines.  so '}if' should be separated by a newline

Comment: suggest this line: 'scanf("%f", &withdraw_amount);'  be modified to 'scanf("%d", &withdraw_amount);'  Then the read in value would never have a fractional part, which wont quite compile, but since no values actually need to be float, make them all int.  the convert later, to float, if necessary

Comment: Given that float values, in C, cannot exactly represent every whole number,  suggest when using the floor function for comparison, to allow for a small variation to be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure it is in fact a whole number, you could round it and compare that to the number itself, but you first need to declare it as an float:

```
float amount_nodes;
//some code 

if (floor(amount_notes) != amount_notes) {        
    printf("Invalid amount, it's not a whole number - Ensure the amount is a whole number.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

But if you want to make sure that `amount_nodes` is a multiple of 50 and a whole number (so for example `50`, `150`, `550`) than you could just check the reminder, before you divide by 50:

```
if (amount_notes % 50f != 0f) {
    printf("Invalid amount - Ensure the amount is a multiple of 50.\n");

    return 0;
}
amount_notes = withdraw_amount / 50;
withdraw_balance = balance_amount - withdraw_amount;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison is always `false` as `amount_notes` is a `int` as you declared.

```
if (amount_notes != (int)amount_notes)  
//its equivalent to
//if ( `int` amount_notes != int amount_notes )
//which will always be false
```

Change data type of `amount_notes` to `float` in the declaration part
This will ensure your `if` condition make sense

```
float amount_notes; //in declaration part
//...else all your code is cool

if (amount_notes != (int)amount_notes){
//now it says
//if ( `float` amount_notes != (int)amount_notes)
printf("Invalid amount - Ensure the amount is a multiple of 50.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int temp; // read into temporary unsigned int. Also solves the problem 
                   // of withdrawing negative numbers
scanf("%u", &temp);
if (temp % 50) 
{ // not evenly divisible by 50, print error and return.
    printf("Invalid amount - Ensure the amount is a multiple of 50.\n");

    return 0;
}

withdraw_amount = temp; // assign temporary value to float
amount_notes = withdraw_amount / 50; // continue as before
...
/* remove this:
if (amount_notes != (int)amount_notes) {
//HERE THE PROBLEM, HOW TO STOP HERE IF THE AMOUNT_NOTES IN NOT AN INTEGER
    printf("Invalid amount - Ensure the amount is a multiple of 50.\n");

    return 0;

}else{*/
```

Should add checks to return code of scanf so you know reading is valid.

Answer (score 1):

> stop if the value of amount_notes is not an integer

Do not define `amount_notes` as integer.

For example do

```
float amount_notes;
```